# MYSQL query where curdate() < 25 doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I really I wonder that when I execute a query like

```
update club_name set wmmr_report=0 where CURDATE() > 15
```

It executes fine and update the record. But when I run the same query like

```
update club_name set wmmr_report=0 where CURDATE() < 25
```

The query returns 0 rows effected.
Assuming Current Date is 19th.

Thanks.

Comment: curdate returns something like `2014-08-19`. Doing `'2014-08-19' < 25` is pretty nonsensical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) function

```
update club_name set wmmr_report=0 where DAY(CURDATE()) < 25
```

DAY() is a synonym for DAYOFMONTH

> DAYOFMONTH(date)
>
> Returns the day of the month for date, in the range 1 to 31, or 0 for
>   dates such as '0000-00-00' or '2008-00-00' that have a zero day part

Comment: @Pawan Just to make double double sure, you know that CURDATE() runs off the system time and not any data in the table? As in when it is the 19th VMai's answer will update ALL rows.. and when it is the 25th it will update NO rows, no matter what the row contains; even if it has a DEFAULT or ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

Comment: @Arth Ya I understand that. Thank you for your caution though.

Comment: @Pawan Cheers, just didn't want anyone savaging their database!